# Oauth2 Scope for invoices in Xero API?

Tags: xero-api

What is the correct scope to generate invoices using the Xero API?

The docs say I should direct users to the following URL:

```
https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize?
  response_type=code&
  client_id=YOURCLIENTID&
  redirect_uri=YOURREDIRECTURI&
  scope=openid profile email accounting.transactions&
  state=123
```

And says:

- scope permissions to request ([links to here](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/scopes))

But I can't see anything that clearly states "Invoicing" or "Create invoice" unless its one of the following:

**Accounting API**

```
accounting.transactions
accounting.transactions.read
accounting.reports.read
accounting.journals.read
accounting.settings
accounting.settings.read
accounting.contacts
accounting.contacts.read
accounting.attachments
accounting.attachments.read
```

What values do I need to pass as the scope parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoice interactions are included in the set of business transactions covered by the accounting.transactions scope (and accounting.transactions.read for read-only actions).

Comment: Note the scopes page has now been updated to include the specific endpoints covered by each scope: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/scopes